# Approximation for average thermal photon number

Tags: statistical-mechanics, photons, thermal-radiation, quantum-optics, approximations

I am currently reading the book *Introductory Quantum Optics* by Gerry and Knight and I am having trouble understanding an approximation they make. In the chapter on thermal fields they derive the average number of photons of the thermal field to be,

$$\overline{n} = \frac{1}{\exp(\hbar \omega / k_B T)-1}.$$

They then proceed to say that evidently this implies,

$$\overline{n} \approx \begin{cases} \frac{k_B T}{\hbar \omega} & (k_B T \gg \hbar \omega) \\
\frac{\hbar \omega}{k_B T} & (k_B T \ll \hbar \omega) \end{cases}.$$
I arrive at the first approximation (for $k_B T \gg \hbar \omega$) if I expand the exponential and neglect terms of order two and higher but I don't see how I can get the other approximation. Can anyone tell me how one arrives at this approximation?

Comment: I am not sure how the second approximation is even correct, because if T is very small, the expression is 1 divided by something very large, which gives n \approx 0. Or, if you want to have a distribution, it is a Boltzmann distribution. Pay attention to the Eq. 2.153, there they do the same limit and obtain exp(-hw/kT).